# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm on Error fails on Insufficient Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to create an alarm if my a json log message is of error log level. My filter works fine but when I create my alarm, it always fails on insufficient data. Seemingly, because there are no errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way around this was to define **two metrics** with the same name but with inverse filters. The filter that matches error level log messages must return a **metric value of `1`**, while the second filter should match all messages, or at least one message within the time period and return a **metric value of `0`**. The presence of the `0` value avoids the insufficient data error.

When the alarm is created from the metric, both filters are combined. If a sum statistic is applied and a alarm rule of `>0` applied, the alarm will trigger only when error messages arrive and not run into insufficient data.

Here is an example using the `boto3` client:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('logs')
logGroupName = 'myLogGroup'
# create this SNS topic with your email subscription...
env['aws_sns_arn_error_email'] = 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:1234567:log_error'

env['sys_type'] = 'production'

metricsNamespace = 'LogMetrics'
metricName = 'ErrorCount' + "_%(sys_type)s" % env

print colors.cyan('Put metric $(metricName)s' % env)

cloudwatch_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = cloudwatch_client.put_metric_data(
    Namespace=metricsNamespace,
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': metricName,
            'Unit': 'Count',
            'Value': 1
        },
    ]
)

logs_client = boto3.client('logs')
print colors.cyan('Put metric filter $.levelname-ERROR')
logs_client.put_metric_filter(
    logGroupName=env.log_group_name_ea,
    filterName='levelname-ERROR',
    filterPattern='{ $.levelname = "ERROR" }',
    metricTransformations=[
        {
            'metricNamespace': metricsNamespace,
            'metricValue': '0',
            'metricName': metricName,
        }]

)
print colors.cyan('Put metric filter catchAll')
logs_client.put_metric_filter(
    logGroupName=env.log_group_name_ea,
    filterName="catchAll",
    filterPattern='',
    metricTransformations=[
        {
            'metricNamespace': metricsNamespace,
            'metricValue': '1',
            'metricName': metricName,
        }]
)

print colors.cyan('Put metric alarm, email on error')

response = cloudwatch_client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='email on error',
    AlarmDescription='email on error',
    ActionsEnabled=True,

    AlarmActions=[
        env.aws_sns_arn_error_email,
    ],

    MetricName=metricName,
    Namespace=metricsNamespace,
    Statistic='Sum',
    Period=300,
    Unit='Count',
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    Threshold=0,
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanThreshold'
)
```